# Update YAML parameter file from CLI

Tags: linux, sed, yaml, command-line-interface

I have a question regarding mkdocs YAML file update from the CLI. YAML file has following string:

```
...
site_name: Material for MkDocs
...
```

What I need is to manipulate `site_name` parameter:

1. add `src/` before
2. remove all spaces and special characters from parameter.

Output should be:

```
...
site_name: src/MaterialforMkDocs
#OR
site_name: src/Material_for_MkDocs
...
```

I did following and looks that it's working:

```
newSiteName=$(grep "site_name:" mkdocs.yml | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/[^a-z  A-Z 0-9 _]//g' | sed 's/site_name/site_name: src\//')

sed -i "s|site_name:.*|$newSiteName|" mkdocs.yml
```

I strongly believe that this could be solved in much easy way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One call to sed:

```
sed -E '
    /^[[:blank:]]*site_name:[[:blank:]]*/ {
        h                       ;# copy the line
        s///                    ;# remove the previous regex
        s/[[:blank:]]+/_/g      ;# convert whitespace to underscores
        s,^,src/,               ;# add the prefix
        x                       ;# swap hold and pattern spaces
        s/:.*/: /               ;# remove the value
        G                       ;# append the hold space
        s/\n//                  ;# remove the newline
    }
' mkdocs.yml
```

If it looks right; add the `-i` option.

Comment: Amazing! Only one point left, it does not remove special characters, e.g. if I have `Mk!Docs` in parameter, it will left, so I update your call and add `s/[^a-z A-Z 0-9 _]//g   ;# remove special characters` right after `s///` in your call and it does the work!
Input `site_name: Material for Mk!Docs`
Output `site_name: src/Material_for_MkDocs`

Comment: `[^[:alnum:]_]` is more concise but equally descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [yq](http://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) - a tool specifically for yaml docs, including editing front-matter:

```sh
yq e --front-matter=process '.site_name |= "src/" + sub("[^a-zA-Z]", "")' file.yaml
```

See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/front-matter#process-front-matter

Disclosure: I wrote yq